# Auto-Rayout position problem when turning the screen

Tags: swift, rotation, ios-autolayout, snapkit

When I used SnapKit to configure auto-layout, I implemented the buttons as shown below.

Even though the screen has changed horizontally, the value of frame.width is still calculated as the value when it is vertical.

If the screen was horizontal when the first app was launched, frame.width will continue to be calculated as the horizontal mode value.

Do I need to update the constraint to reflect the changed direction of width?

```swift
nextButton.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
    make.left.equalTo(buttonView.snp.left).offset(self.view.frame.width / 2) // <- here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to update the width constraint during transition.Below is the method that will be called during layout transition(orientation change).

```
func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, 
                   with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

you can override this method and use the to update the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `self.view.frame.width / 2` is a fixed amount. It isn't going to magically change itself later just because the `frame.width` changes.

The fact is that this was a poor way to construct the constraint. The whole point of autolayout is to do things *relative* to other things, *not* to hard-code numbers like this. You are trying to put the left edge of the button at the horizontal center of `self.view`, so why don't you just say so in the first place?